# Xcode generated NSManagedObject subclass errors

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, xcode4

I'm having a ton of errors for my generated model objects:

ExerciseSet.h

```
1  @class Exercise;
2 
3  @interface ExerciseSet : NSManagedObject
4 
5  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * order;
6  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * reps;
7  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * weight;
8  @property (nonatomic, retain) Exercise *belongsTo;
9
10 @end
```

- `Illegal interface qualifier` on line 1.
- `Expected identifier or '('` on line 3.
- `Unknown type name 'Exercise'` on line 8
- `Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type` on line 8.
- Warning for all properties for not calling `@synthesize`, or `@dynamic`(which of course are called)

Exercise.h

```
1  @class ExerciseName, ExerciseSet, Workout, WorkoutMethod;
2
3  @interface Exercise : NSManagedObject
4
5  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * notes;
6  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * restBetweenSets;
7  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rmMethod;
8  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * rmResult;
9  @property (nonatomic, retain) Workout *belongsTo;
10 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *hasSet;
11 @property (nonatomic, retain) WorkoutMethod *isDoneWith;
12 @property (nonatomic, retain) ExerciseName *takesNameFrom;
13 @end
14 
15 @interface Exercise (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
16 
17 - (void)addHasSetObject:(ExerciseSet *)value;
18 - (void)removeHasSetObject:(ExerciseSet *)value;
19 - (void)addHasSet:(NSSet *)values;
20 - (void)removeHasSet:(NSSet *)values;
21 @end
```

- `Illegal interface qualifier` on line 1.
- `Missing @end` on line 3.
- `Unknown type name 'Workout'` on line 9.
- etc.

The other forward declared interfaces are ok, with no problems or errors.

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Xcode 4.3, regenerated the `NSManagedObject` subclasses and the errors disappeared. It must've been a bug in Xcode.

Thanks for your help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, turns out that one of my .h files was missing `@end`
That's also why regenerating your NSManagedObjects worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put here how Exercise is being defined? Your code seem correct but it seems that you have an error on the class Exercise

Meantime try to change

```
@class Exercise
```

For:

```
#import "Exercise.h"
```

Comment: I could compile your code with NSObject instead of NSManagedObject, I dont know if it will work for you